# Сreating Entity with a field storing an array BigDecimal Hibernate

Tags: java, arrays, spring, hibernate, entity

I have a table "Layout" in a database that needs to be mapped to an entity:[image]

In the database the required field "camera ids" is of type "numeric[]".

There is a table "Camera", which is represented in the database like this:

[image]

In the database, the required field "camera id" is of type "numeric".

The main question is how to create an entity "Layout" in Hibernate to match the presented table?
maybe organize operations in repository for layout?

Answer (score 1):

Your "Layout" table seems to violate **NF1** ([First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Satisfying_1NF)), which states that columns containing sets of values are not allowed.

You could create a mapping table (with columns layout_id, camera_id).

Maybe you have a reason to not normalize that table - in that case you might add that reason to your question.

For the Layout entity:

Your Entity would have some kind of set/list of "Camera" entities OR your layout does not know about the Cameras, in which case your cameras would need a foreign key of their matching "Layout".
I can recommend looking into a very helpful [article adressing those types of mapping](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) by Vlad Mihalcea.

Comment: some advised to write a hibernate query for these purposes, but I do not know how it should look and where it is more correct to place it

Comment: maybe we are talking about the use of HQL

Comment: my main task on request  controller  is to issue a json response, the fields of which are identical to the fields of the table Layout

Comment: hand me
create a sign that sets the correspondence between the layout ID and the camera ID?